# Using if statement with http response text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using vanilla JavaScript in this code. I created a variable of responseText and implement it on the if statement and even if condition A is true, it didn't work.

```
  setInterval(()=>{
  
  var http =new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("GET","send.php",true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange= function(){
  
  if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
  var pu = http.responseText;
 
 if(pu == "0"){
 
//do A

} else {
 // Do B
}

  }
  
  } 
  
  
  http.send();
  }, 1000)
```

The send.php file

```
<?php

session_start();

include"dbh.inc.php";

?>

<?php

  $sqll =  "SELECT * FROM `like-unlikes` WHERE `post_user`='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND `Stauts`=0";
 
 $queryy = mysqli_query($conn, $sqll);
 
 if($queryy){
 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($queryy) > 0){
 
echo "0";
 
 } else {
 
 echo "1";
 
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Even if condition A is true it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't worked @Muhammed

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0):

please check through console.log() method that what data is coming. In many cases, PHP returns data other than echoed data. For removing this place the following line in start of your file inside PHP tags

```
ob_start();
```

Before the condition in which you echo your data, Place the following line

```
ob_end_clean();
```

You can see what these commands do on PHP documentation